# How to deploy multiple Spring boot applications with external configurations on the same Tomcat?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

When I want to deploy multiple Spring-Boot applications on the same tomcat I face multiple problems.

1) Both applications have to run independent while sharing the same tomcat. When deploying two Spring-Boot application on the same tomcat I get the following Exception:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-03-06 17:31:01 ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-2)] with key 'dataSource'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:625)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.lambda$registerBeans$2(MBeanExporter.java:551)
    at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:551)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterSingletonsInstantiated(MBeanExporter.java:434)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5267)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:629)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1839)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:137)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:671)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:615)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

2) I need to provide external configurations for both applications and it needs to be clear that each application uses the right configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) When two Spring-Boot applications run on the same tomcat you will normally face the issue that the instantiation of a datasource might fail, because an instance with the same name already exists. This is the exception you described in your question.

This can be solved by adding a unique name to each Spring-Boot application e.g. in the

`application.yml`

```
spring:
  application:
    name: application-name-1
  jmx:
    default-domain: application-name-1
```

2) Providing an external configuration for each Spring-Boot application can be done by tomcat context configurations for every application individually. Assuming that all applications are deployed as `.war` e.g. `app1.war`, `app2.war` we need to configure the context for both applications as the following:

create the following files (and directories if missing)

```
tomcat-base-dir
  /conf
    /catalina
      /localhost #must be the same as specified in the Host tag in the server.xml
        app1.xml #must have the same name as the .war application file
        app2.xml
```

Content for the `app1.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- docBase must contain be the name of the application to be configured -->
<Context docBase="app1.war"> 
    <Parameter name="spring.config.location" value="${catalina.base}/conf/app1.yml" />
</Context>
```

This will configure the application `app1.war` to use the file `app1.yml` for configuration. Do the same for app2. The actual configuration file `app1.yml` can be located at any path specified in the value.